# On a mouse button click,how do i know the widget present at that location in gtk?

Tags: window, gtk

I am having multiple windows on a parent window.When I click on a particular window, how do I come to know that which window is present at that particular location ?Is there a function for it?

Comment: Please show code. Also state your GTK+ version. Also note that mouse events already go to the right widget in question.

Comment: What prevents you from connecting to the mouse event signals on the widgets you want to know about?